# Using pdfmake - generate pdf tool in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

Using 'bower install pdfmake'
I've downloaded the relevant files in order to work with pdfMake.

I want to work with this library in angular.

This is my sample code

angular controller:

```
    $scope.pdfMaker = function(){
        var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    }
```

html:

```
 <button ng-click="pdfMaker()">run pdf</button>
```

What am I missing? why this does not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it!
I missed to import of the pdfMake plugin in my home html file.

Comment: Are you able to get raw Html to work with this?  I can get static text to work as above, but not HTML.

Comment: what was the import?